# Xamarin studio debug Android app

Tags: android, debugging, xamarin

I have build it and no error founded. But when debugging into my android device (5.0 lollipop) it shows a black screen about 1 to 2 seconds and get out back to the home screen. Is there anything wrong wrong here?

```
namespace myfirstapp
{
    [Activity (Label = "myfirstapp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);


            Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.btnAdd);

            button.Click += delegate {                
                EditText number1 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtNum1);
                EditText number2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtNum2);
                TextView res = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtResult);
                int result =  Convert.ToInt32(number1.Text)+ Convert.ToInt32(number2.Text);
                res.Text = result.ToString();
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried to clear the code and rebuild it?